# Mocha test fails before Promise resolves

Tags: node.js, async-await, timeout, mocha.js, es6-promise

I have a Mocha test in NodeJS:

```
it('Test', async () => {
    this.party = new Party('example_id');
    await this.party.startWithPlaylist('3e8JNsQmYEXtfV7K1M0pAb');
    assert.isTrue(this.party.getStreamingProvider().getAuth().getToken() !== undefined);
})
```

With `this.party.startWithPlaylist` being:

```
startWithPlaylist(id) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        assert.ok(id !== undefined);
        await this.start();
        let playlist = await this.songInfoProvider.getPlaylist(id);
        resolve();
    });
}
```

The code is working correctly, but my test is not. 2 Seconds after starting the test I get the error:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

After the error occurs `startWithPlaylist` finishes correctly but as it seems not in time for my test.

I've looked through Stackoverflow and found similar problems but none with an accepted answer or any other hint that works for me. I already tried to change the test from `async` to just waiting for the promise to resolve with `.then` but none of my attempts made it work.

I would really appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could try increaing the timeout of the test `(this.timeout(5000)` to see if the promise is taking longer than 2 seconds to complete. Or maybe log timestamps inside of `startWithPlaylist` and see how long it takes to resolve.

Comment: That's exactly what I did a minute ago! And it's working. Because the promise has to do multiple http requests it needs more than 2s to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the time that function needs to execute is higher than the timeout provided.

Yo can chan using `this.timeout(...)` in multiple ways. Docs [here](https://mochajs.org/#timeouts)

One way is like this, but exists multiple options: suite/test/hook level...

```js
it('Test', async () => {
  this.party = new Party('example_id');
  await this.party.startWithPlaylist('3e8JNsQmYEXtfV7K1M0pAb');
  assert.isTrue(this.party.getStreamingProvider().getAuth().getToken() !== undefined);
}).timeout(4000)
```

or using [parameters in command line](https://mochajs.org/#command-line-usage) when running mocha in this way:

```
mocha test --timeout 4000
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you actually define the arg. "id" when running it?

Comment: Yes I did. (You can see the id being `3DiOnTOzRokGNlFaFUonCy` in the first snippet).

Comment: Try putting the output into a variable

Comment: Changing it to `let output = await this.party.startWithPlaylist('3e8JNsQmYEXtfV7K1M0pAb')` didn't change anything.

Comment: I'm gonna do some more research on the package you're using.